# To show directory structure as a tree similarly as Pstree

Tags: unix, tree, directory

I would like to see my current directory structure as a tree such that no directories below the current directory is shown, similarly as `Pstree`. 
I did not find an option for that from `ls` in OS X Leopard.

How can you make a tree of your current directory structure in terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a command to do this called "tree" on many Unix operating systems but I don't know if it's available in MacOS X

Comment: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/ It's not installed by default, but is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install tree by yourself. Simply follow instructions here:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2025

Then, you will be able to produce nice looking trees:

```
> tree tree_sample --charset=ascii
tree_sample
|-- a
|   `-- file_aa
|-- b
|-- c
|-- file_a
`-- file_b
```

Comment: This is reproduction of ephemient's comment with mostly new-link only new piece of information. Please, provide at least a reference to such a fact. Please, also explain your point about the link. Now, it is about basic installation instructions.